# Interpretation of velocity-velocity and acceleration-acceleration curves

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity, calculus, displacement

I am parametrizing equations of motion in the form:
$$x(t) = x_0+v_{0,x}t\\y(t) = y_0+v_{0,y}t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
The parametrized equation with respect to time:
$$y(x) = y_0+v_{0,y}\cdot \frac{x - x_0}{v_{0,x}}+\frac{1}{2}a\cdot \left(\frac{x - x_0}{v_{0,x}}\right)^2.$$
The interpretation of the last equation is trajectory.

What I struggle with is the interpretation for similar equations expressed for velocities and acceleration. Is there any interpretation of $v_y(v_x)$ and $a_y(a_x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x component of velocity and acceleration are constants; you don't use them as function variables. Even if you treat them as variables, the y component and the x component of both velocity and acceleration are independent of each other; the change in the x component makes no difference to the y component. These are not valid functions

Comment: Therefore they have no physical meaning? This is what you imply here?

Comment: yes. They do not have physical meanings like y(x)